# In React, rendering must always be a pure calculation?

Tags: reactjs

In https://react.dev/learn/render-and-commit#step-2-react-renders-your-components

It says:

> Rendering must always be a pure calculation:
>
> Same inputs, same output. Given the same inputs, a component should
> always return the same JSX.

The thing is, it already talked about states (`useState()`) in the previous chapter, so how can the rendering be pure, when the first time, it renders a count of `0`, but with the same props (or no props) at all, next time it renders a count of `1` (in the counter example)? This is totally impure but the docs says it must be pure. Can somebody explain is it pure or impure?

Comment: It's not the same props if the value is different...

Comment: it is no props for `<Counter />` so the props stay the same, but the renderings are different

Comment: In the context of that quote, you should think of the state as an input

Comment: [Edit] your question to show what you're talking about. In some manner, the input to the render process differs.

Comment: I think I would agree that this pitfall is a little confusing for the reason you describe. I wouldn't get too concerned about this though and instead just understand the principle: Re-renders will be unpredictable, don't rely on their count, order, or anything else. Always use React mechanisms like useState and useEffect to manage persistent values or side-effects.

Comment: @NicholasTower that makes it weird but I guess it can explain why they say that. A component with a state is never thought to be "a pure function" before, and now they are saying it is a pure function

Answer (score 2):

You should think of there being *three* inputs to a component: the props, the state, and the context. If all three of those are the inputs, then you should write your rendering logic to be a pure calculation. If all 3 are unchanged, then the output should be unchanged. But if any one changes, then the output can change.

They could probably have described this a bit better in the section you quote, especially because it deviates from the [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) idea of a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Though if you follow the link to [this page](https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure), they do discuss that some more.

> Although you might not have used them all yet, in React there are three kinds of inputs that you can read while rendering: props, state, and context.